# How to "quote" for a discount

Tags: expressions

Often on advertising material, one will see instructions to "quote *(phrase)* for a discount", for example when booking a hotel or other service.  [Examples here](https://skillsmatter.com/conferences/6712-droidcon-2015#venue), [here](http://www.theadvisory.co.uk/online-estate-agents.php) [and here](http://www.bath.ac.uk/hr/working/pay-reward/benefits/staff-discounts/).

How would one be expected to quote such a phrase?

> Hello, can I quote *(often odd-sounding) phrase* please?

strikes me as awkward.

Comment: In the US, we say "*use* discount code xxxxx", not "*quote* discount code xxxxx".  It's just a way to say that by quoting to them the discount code, you'll get the discount.

Answer (score 1):

If you are booking or purchasing online, there is usually a place to enter a discount code.  If you are doing so by phone or in person, they will often ask if you have any discounts.  If not, simply say that you have a discount code, say where you found it, and either say it or show the clerk a copy.

Answer (score 0):

In US usage, the phrase *mention [code, term, or phrase] when ordering for a x% discount* is often seen.

When filling out an online form, the phrase *enter [code, term, or phrase] in the **Discount Code** box/field* is common.

Comment: "In US usage, the phrase mention [code, term, or phrase] when ordering for a x% discount is often seen."  I'm sure it is, but this does not answer my question.  *How* should one mention it?

Comment: Hello, can I have the [*xyz*] discount please?

Answer (score 0):

You can assume "quote" means "mention" (but requests that you use the exact string) and when you get to the pricing part of the conversation, say something like "I have discount code XYZ" and ask them to apply that.